# iframe facebook app with woobox

Tags: facebook, ssl, https

I recently made a iframe app/page for my FB fan page with woobox. I have 100% SSL hosting, however, a lot of users are saying that they are unable to load this iframe site. Everything works 100% for me and many other visitors, but some are saying that page displays some server connection error. Any ideas? Manye I need to include some FB scripts in order for iframe page to work 100%?
When I load the app with this iframe, connection is secure so SSL shouldnt be the prob. I did however get very cheap SSL, can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Likely what is happening is that while your Facebook connection is secure, the contest in the iframe is still pointing at the http:// version of your page and not the https:// version. Most static iframe apps aren't smart enough to check this, so they serve insecure content on a secure page.

The majority of browsers will be fine with this, but some people might have their browser security settings tweaked a little bit differently and that's probably where you're seeing people unable to access your frame content.

An easy solution is to just have the static iframe app ALWAYS direct to your https:// content, that way, what you're serving is secure whether or not the user is browsing facebook on http:// or https://